# After parsing the JSON the output is array ( )

Tags: php, html, json, parsing

So here is the `json` [file](http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/Clan?clan=274879547254)

I need to display `name`, `score`, `warsWon`, `WarsLost` in a *html* page, inside header tag.

And I need to display `userName`, `role` , `level` of all the players in a *html* table.

I am using the following code but the output is `array()`

```
<?php
$a = 'http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/Clan?clan=274879547254'; // place your JSON here. If string, add signle quotes around it.

$arr = json_decode($a, TRUE);

$names = $arr['name'];
$score = $arr['score'];
$warsWon = $arr['warsWon'];
$warsLost = $arr['warsLost'];

$users = array();
if (! empty($arr['players'])) {
  foreach ($arr['players'] as $player) {

    $users[$player['avatar']['userId']]['userName'] = $player['avatar']['userName'];
    $users[$player['avatar']['userId']]['role'] = $player['avatar']['role'];
    $users[$player['avatar']['userId']]['level'] = $player['avatar']['level'];
  }
}
 echo '<pre>';
print_r($users);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

[Here](http://ashishpatel.in/clan.php) is the output of the above code

Can anyone tell me what is the error ?

Comment: Remove ['avatar'] from  $player['avatar']['userName']

Comment: It looks like json_decode() wants JSON, but you are giving it a URL. Fetch the JSON data first, then pass the result to json_parse().

Comment: I tried it, but its still not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = json_decode($a, TRUE);
```

is decoding the JSON from the **string** of the URL, not the **content** of the URL (you're decoding `http://.....` instead of `{id:....`)

So instead, you need to get the data that is on the other side of the URL.

So change that line to:

```
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents($a), TRUE);
```